# Como fazer uma especialização exclusiva no sql?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Bom, terminei o diagrama entidade relacionamento do banco de dados que estou criando e nele existe uma entidade serviço, que possui duas especializações excludentes (uma ou outra, não pode ser ambas), mensal e simples.

Na implementação gerou 3 tabelas, mensal e simples tem como chave estrangeira o identificador de serviço, porém, como posso fazer para impedir que seja possível implementar a mesma instância nessas duas tabelas e fazer valer esse exclusivo?

Comment: Se entendi seu problema resolsi um caso parecido por uma triggercde statement , a tigger validava acregra.

Comment: Se for MySQL pode usar Schedule, no Oracle é (Jobs ou Scheduler), vai ter que implementar as restrições nesses gatilhos disponíveis em cada SGBD.